# Custom Validator not working in zend

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, date, zend-form

so I wrote a custom date validater called Date and when I try and use it, zend falls back to the zend_validate_date call:

```
    $datePosted = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('datePosted');
    $datePosted->setLabel('Date Job Was Posted?: ')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('stripTags')
            ->addFilter('stringTrim')
            ->addPrefixPath('Hg2_Validate_Date', 'Hg2/Validate/', 'validate')
            ->addValidators(array(
                array(
                    'validator' => 'NotEmpty',
                    'breackChainOnFailure' => true
                ),
                array(
                    'validator' => 'stringLength',
                    'options' => array(0, 10)
                ),
                array(
                    'validator' => 'Date'
                ),
                array(
                    'validator' => 'alnum',
                    'options' => array('allowWhiteSpaces' => true)
                )
            ));

    return $datePosted;
```

This is what I have and it should use my date and not zends date no?

the custom validation can be seen by the addPrefixPath() where I add my custom validator to this element. My understanding is that now if I call Date or date bellow in the 'validator' it will call my date and not zends?

Comment: Is `Hg2` in your `include_path`?

Comment: First thing i would try `'validator' => 'Hg2_Validate_Date'` or `'validator' => new Hg2_Validate_Date()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a prefix you don't have to add the `_Date` to the path. If you look at the documentation

```
addPrefixPath($prefix, $path, $type = null)
adds a prefix/path association to the loader specified by $type.
```

With your current prefix argument this will probably extend to a class named `Hg2_Validate_Date_Date` which it will not find.

So this should work for you

```
->addPrefixPath('Hg2_Validate', 'Hg2/Validate/', 'validate')
```

Comment: Also, just to be sure: Your validator class is in the file `library/Hg/Validate/Date.php`.